# spinner not align equal to edittext box

Tags: android

How do I set spinner? In my code spinner and edit text box layout margin left and right is look equal in simulator but when I deploy on real device spinner look bigger form left and right side as compare to edit text box how do I set equal both edittext box and spinner in all screen?

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


      <EditText    
        android:id="@+id/txtMobileNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:gravity="left"     
        android:hint="@string/MobileNo"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/txtPinNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:gravity="left"      
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="@string/PinNo"/>

</LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="0.1"
             android:weightSum="1"
             android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/lgnspinner"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:prompt="@string/network_prompt"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: provide a snapshot, as to how you want them to be. BTW, your **xml** is mal-formed. You sure it even worked on the first hand?

Comment: have you set Spinner dataset

Comment: Cant you just set both EditText and Spinner width to something like 100dp or 200dp?